# Updating table in SubForm with new changes to structure from linked table

Tags: ms-access

I have a manual table in Access, and a subform that links to that manual table. It all works fine i.e. I can edit the table in the subform and it reflects in the manual table.

I have now made some changes to the manual table (added in some look up fields and validation), however the changes have not been reflected in the subform i.e. the validation isnt there and neither are the lookup list boxes. If I input a new subform from the manual table then the new subform does have it there.

Obviously I could just replace the subform with a new subform, but I have already put in a lot of code for the subform and I want to make changes as I work. Is there a way of making the subform update from the manual table the changes I have made?

Many thanks
Nick

Comment: Some changes to table field, such as adding lookup configuration, should display a 'alert' box next to the property in the table with options to 'Update all lookup properties wherever [field name] is used' or 'Help on propagating field properties'. Once the table is saved, this 'alert' will no longer be presented. However, adding a new field will not modify form design.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I'll take a look again when I'm next back in the office! :)

Comment: I never set these properties in table. I just build comboboxes on form.